# How to make matplotlib.pyplot.figure resize apply to 2 graphs?

Tags: python

I have a function creating 2 different graphs. I am using `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`  to resize the graphs. However, it is only applying to the first graph. Any fix for this to make it work for both?

```
def func_extract_activecases_plot(dayssinces,Active_Cases_arrays,name_states):
        
        
        figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
        
        plt.bar(dayssinces,Active_Cases_arrays)
        plt.title('Covid 19 Active Cases For '+ name_states )
        plt.xlabel('Days Since 1st Case')
        plt.ylabel('Number of people/cases')

        plt.show()
        
        
        
        x = dayssinces
        y = Active_Cases_arrays

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        
        plt.plot(x,y,marker='.')
        
        gamma=len(x)
        for i,j in zip(x,y):
            ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))
        plt.title('Covid 19 Active Cases For '+ name_states)
        plt.xlabel('Days Since 1st Case')
        plt.ylabel('Number of people/cases')
      
        plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amslq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating a new figure for that you have to set the settings again.

change the `fig = plt.figure()` to `fig = plt.figure(num=None,figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')`